# Could use someone's expertise with filtering my nested array by a certain value

Tags: javascript, arrays, search, filter

I know there are a ton of "How to filter my array" questions. However, I'm still stuck.

I'm not too familiar with arrays and I'm hoping someone can help me with  my particular situation.

I have an array that I'm trying to filter. I'm looking to return all data if "user.name" or "writers.name" equals "Adam". "user" will only ever have one name, while "writers" can have multiple.

```
    [{
     mediaId: '86699',
     user: {
       name: 'Adam',
       id: '17622'
     },
     nodeType: 'testNode',
     title: 'testTitle',
     id: '23968',
     writers: []
   },
   {
     mediaId: '90547',
     user: {
       name: 'Jake',
       id: '65936'
     },
     nodeType: 'testNode',
     title: 'testTitleTwo',
     id: '89960',
     writers: [{
         name: 'Adam',
         id: '17622'
       },
       {
         name: 'Steve',
         id: '47622'
       }]
   },
   {
     mediaId: '99662',
     user: {
       name: 'James',
       id: '22236'
     },
     nodeType: 'testNode',
     title: 'testTitleThree',
     id: '89960',
     writers: [{
       name: 'Paul',
       id: '27622'
     }]
   }
 ]
```

Desired output:

```
[{
    "mediaId": "86699",
    "user": {
      "name": "Adam",
      "id": "17622"
    },
    "nodeType": "testNode",
    "title": "testTitle",
    "id": "23968",
    "writers": []
  },
  {
    "mediaId": "90547",
    "user": {
      "name": "Jake",
      "id": "65936"
    },
    "nodeType": "testNode",
    "title": "testTitleTwo",
    "id": "89960",
    "writers": [{
        "name": "Adam",
        "id": "17622"
      },
      {
        "name": "Steve",
        "id": "45389"
      }]
  }
]
```

Thank you in advance!!!

**UPDATED:** Everything is the same except that user and writers are now wrapped around properties.

```
[{
   mediaId: '86699',
   nodeType: 'testNode',
   title: 'testTitle',
   id: '23968',
   properties: {
     user: {
       name: 'Adam',
       id: '17622'
     },
     writers: []
   }
 }, {
   mediaId: '90547',
   nodeType: 'testNode',
   title: 'testTitleTwo',
   id: '89960',
   properties: {
     user: {
       name: 'Jake',
       id: '65936'
     },
     writers: [{
       name: 'Adam',
       id: '17622'
     }, {
       name: 'Steve',
       id: '47622'
     }]
   }
 }, {
   mediaId: '99662',
   nodeType: 'testNode',
   title: 'testTitleThree',
   id: '89960',
   properties: {
     user: {
       name: 'James',
       id: '22236'
     },
     writers: [{
       name: 'Paul',
       id: '27622'
     }]
   }
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply a filter, you are essentially iterating over each item in the array and seeing if it matches your criteria. Return `true` if you want it to stay, and return `false` if you want it to be filtered out.

So at the top-most layer, you have an array of objects, each of which appears to represent a node (judging by the "nodeType" property). We start with this:

```js
const matches = array.filter(node => {
  // criteria go here
  return true; // or false
});
```

What are the criteria? Well it should remain if...

1. The node.user.name is "Adam"
2. Of the writers, at least one has writer.name === "Adam"

Let's define those.

```js
const hasUserNameAdam = (node) => node?.user?.name === "Adam";
const hasWriterNameAdam = (writer) => writer?.name === "Adam";
```

We can do the same thing with the writer array to handle the second layer.

```js
const arrayHasWriterNameAdam = writerArray.some(writer => hasWriterNameAdam(writer));
```

Now we just need to plug them in.

```js
const matches = data.filter(node => {
  const hasUserNameAdam = (node) => node?.user?.name === "Adam";
  const hasWriterNameAdam = (writer) => writer?.name === "Adam";
  const arrayHasWriterNameAdam = (writerArray) => writerArray.some(writer => hasWriterNameAdam(writer));

  return hasUserNameAdam(node) || arrayHasWriterNameAdam(node?.writers);
});
```

And we can choose to refactor those inner functions back to being in line to clean things up, if we would like.

```js
const matches = data.filter(node => node?.user?.name === "Adam" || node?.writers?.some(writer => writer?.name === "Adam"));
```

**Update**

Or with the updated object shape, the `user` and `writers` props are nested under the `properties` prop, so we only have to add the `.properties` layer to everywhere we access the `user` and `writers` properties to adapt.

```js
const matches = data.filter(node => node?.properties?.user?.name === "Adam" || node?.properties?.writers?.some(writer => writer?.name === "Adam"));
```

Comment: Hi Jacob. Thanks for the great write up. I had a bit of an update on the array. I edited my original question. Would you be able to update your answer for the updated array. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, we just have to access the `user` and `writers` props through the `properties` prop now. I added the final filter with the new data shape at the end of my answer.

Comment: I originally tried that but I got an error. But realized it was because I forgot to update another piece of code. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```js
input.filter(element => element.user.name === 'Adam' || element.writers.some(writer => writer.name === 'Adam'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const findAdam = arr => arr.filter(
element => element.properties.user.name === 'Adam' || element.properties.writers.some(writer => writer.name === 'Adam')
)
```